# jQuery .width() Conditional Always Triggers in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, viewport, response.redirect

I have a client site that switches to a mobile version whenever the viewport size falls within specific paramaters:

```
if($(window).width() < 800) {
    document.location="http://www.website.com/mobile.html";
}
```

In various versions of IE, however, the script always triggers regardless of the viewport width. I've tried a number of different variations, and can't seem to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

ty

Comment: What does `alert($(window).width())` output?

Comment: Please use `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`

Comment: @Ty Morton you should use `.replace()` as suggested by David.

Comment: Doorknob, the alerts return the correct width and height (more or less).

Comment: .replace() does the same thing.

Comment: Doorknob, why did you edit my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be:

```
if($(document).width() < 800) {
    document.location="http://www.website.com/mobile.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
if($(window).width() < 800) {
    document.location("http://www.website.com/mobile.html");
}
```

or you can use

```
if($(window).width() < 800) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.website.com/mobile.html";  
}
```

and try to calculate width like

```
if(document.body.clientWidth < 800){   //Or document.documentElement.clientWidth
     redirect it
}
```

Comment: I'm not having trouble with the redirect. I'm having trouble with the conditional being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
if($(window).outerWidth() < 800) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.website.com/mobile.html";
}
```

Comment: outerWidth still doesn't apply to window or document objects. http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Answer (score 1):

`screen.width` will check the actual size of the screen so it won't redirect desktops with resized windows, and it doesn't rely on `jQuery`.

also, use `window.location.replace()` to avoid polluting the browser history with the redirect page.

```
if(screen.width < 800) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.website.com/mobile.html");
}
```

Comment: I need it to be dependent upon the viewport width, not the screen width. I actually use this in conjunction with a resize listener, so it will change if the user adjusts the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if($(window).outerWidth() < 800) {
    document.location="http://www.website.com/mobile.html";
}
```

Comment: outwerWidth doesn't apply to window or document objects. http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/